# PHP behavior of a new operator

Tags: php

I'm wondering what happens when I do so in PHP:

```
$inst = new stdClass();
$inst->some = 'value';
var_dump(new $inst);
```

Result is a new empty instance of stdClass. Can anybody answer why is it so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you're using the keyword new, which instantiates a new instance.. What are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: Yes, but I do so with instance of class. I expected to see error.

Comment: It is sort of half-documented in the manual, example #5 on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: yes, it's an interesting and strange behavior of `new` keyword. There's no good explanation in documentation for that

Comment: `new self` inside a class needs to work for various reasons.  Essentially, this is what this is resolving to, however, not good practice in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your response guys.